# Reload UIViewController and Dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a turn-based game which allows the user to play many matches simultaneously. After a turn has been taken, the user can click a "Go to next match" button.

When clicking the button, I just create a new GameViewController, and pushes it. However, when doing this, the old GameViewControlller won't dealloc, and sometimes interfear with the new viewController (Like blocks executing increasing the score on the oldView controller, increases the score on the new one).

The reason I want to push a new viewController instead of nuke and cleanup the old one, and reuse it, is because I want the push animation, and for safety reasons, I want a clean one.

So I guess when creating and pushing a new viewcontroller, it isn't really a new one, but the old.

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
            GameViewController *gameViewController = (GameViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"GameViewController"];
            gameViewController.matchObject = match;
            [weakSelf.navigationController pushViewController:gameViewController animated:YES];
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried NSLog in dealloc method to see if it's called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pushing new instance of `GameViewController` but your old controller will not be destroyed since it stored in navigation controllers' stack. There is a potential memory leak - if you push new controller for each turn and never pop it.

You may directly update navigation stack after new controller animation finishes by changing the [UINavigationController.viewControllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/viewControllers) property. 
(e.g. something like

```
// I assume you using ARC.
NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray array];
[temp addObjectsFromArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers]
[temp removeObjectAtIndex:temp.count - 2];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = [temp copy];
```

but this solution does not looks good to me anyway)

You may use nice push transition without navigation controller, please look at [CATransition](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CATransition_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) class.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Need to set a delay for the deletion though, and let the new one load.

Answer (score 0):

If you just push a new view controller your old view controller will still be there. It just won't be visible, because the new one is on top. You could try something like this (assuming you are not already removing your old view controller somewhere else):

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle: nil];
GameViewController *gameViewController = (GameViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"GameViewController"];
gameViewController.matchObject = match;
[weakSelf.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[weakSelf.navigationController pushViewController:gameViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I believe the current view controller will be destroyed after this line `[weakSelf.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];`, better to use `strong` variable.

Comment: Isn't that what the OP wants? He wants dealloc to be called, so I assume he wants it to be destroyed.

Comment: After line `[weakSelf.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];` the line `[weakSelf.navigationController pushViewController:gameViewController animated:YES];` has no sence, because `weakSelf` will be nil and he will not be able to access to `navigationController`

Comment: Why should weakSelf be nil after this?

Comment: Well, I do not know for 100%, but it looks like this code is performed inside block and `weakSelf` has `__weak` modificator to aviod strong reference cycle. After current controller is popped from navigation stack there will be no references to it and it will be destroyed and all `__weak` references will be nulled-out.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It is very likely a weak reference. But still, why should it be nil after you called the `popViewControllerAnimated:` method on weakSelf's `navigationController` property? weakSelf will be nil, if the original self is deallocated. But I don't see why that should happen here.

Comment: Well, you are right, sorry, I thought current view controller will be deallocated right after it popped from navigation stack, but (I tried) it keeps it alive for some reason...(do you know why?)